# Conditional probability and entropy: How do I interpret given data?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

As the title explains, I never could understand probabilities. It's one of those things that how much I try, I can't quite understand.

I have to do one homework exercise about entropy and I'm given a set of probabilities. I know how to calculate entropy but I don't know how to interpret the given data.

The alphabet is $ S = \{1,2\}$ and the conditional probabilities are $P(1|1)=0.8\ P(2|1)=0.2\ P(1|2)=0.6\ P(2|2)=0.4$ and $P(1,2)=P(2,1)$

I've created this table (don't know if it is right or not):

```
       | X = 1 | X = 2
 Y = 1 |  0,8  |  0,2
 Y = 2 |  0,6  |  0,4
```

I know that I need the probability of $1$ and $2$ to calculate the entropy.
To get the probability of $1$ is like this?
$$P(1) = \frac{P(1,2)}{P(2|1)}$$

If so, How can I get $P(1,2)$?

I know that $P(1)=0.75$ and $P(2)=0.25$ but I don't understand how to get to this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, the explicit solution:
You have,
$$P(1) = \frac{P(1,2)}{P(2|1)}$$
and
$$P(2) = \frac{P(2,1)}{P(1|2)}$$

Because of 
$$P(2,1) = P(1,2)$$
we get:
$$P(1)*P(2|1)=P(2)* P(1|2)$$
$$P(1)=3*P(2)$$
Furthermore, you have $P(1)+P(2)=1$ and hence
$$4*P(2)=1$$,
Hence $$P(2)=0.25$$

Comment: Hi. Thanks but I still don't understand. Don't I need at least $p(1)$ or $p2$? Another question. Is table correct?

Comment: No, u do not need p(1) or p(2). You have to different equations with two variabels P(1) and P(2), so you can solve the system of equations.
I do not know the conventions for the table, hence I judge its correctness.

Comment: Hi. Once again thanks but still don't know how to solve it. I know that $P(1)=0.75$ and $P(2)=0.25$ but I don't understand how to get to this result

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. Thanks. That was so simple. Right in front of my eyes but the truth was that I never saw it. I told I don't understand probabilities :-)